# Port ASP.NET 4 Razor "extensionless URLs" site to ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-webpages, asp.net-core

Since ASP.NET 5 changed the whole architecture around handlers, bootstrapping, etc. I am now stumped as to how to port a site using ASP.NET 4 and "extensionless URLs", "ASP.NET Web Pages" technique to ASP.NET

Before, you would have a few different settings in `web.config to implement that,

1. `System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider` as a build provider for building the `.cshtml` pages
2. `System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule` as a module
3. `<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0" />
   <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />` to activate the whole contraption
4. I am unsure what else is important. Sometimes there's `System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.WebPages.Razor` too, but `web.config` really became too complicated to me. I like the new way.

Anyway, I want to port this to ASP.NET 5 to make it all Linux ready (it is a *chore* to get pure `cshtml` to work on ASP.NET 4 and Mono) and easy to start up.

It would be okay if the actual implementation is different from how it was on ASP.NET 4 and if I'd have to change some things (like getting rid of `_AppStart` in favor of `Startup.cs`?), but I really don't want to use MVC for these pages.

Comment: May I ask out of pure curiosity why you don't want to use MVC? If its about controlling the names you can always define your own routes or just override the route manager with your own custom route engine. I have made MVC work from reading data directly from DB instead of static files... its was fun.. but not to difficult to do :) And the routes were simple like, /Home, /Contact, /Article/TextLookUpValueForSEO -  I was just wondering.

Comment: Well, I looked at some stuff and I found out MVC will be used anyways. They supposedly want to combine Web API, Web Pages and MVC all into MVC itself, but the Web Pages part seems to be unfinished. I suppose it probably works by fidding with the API enough - but hey, whatever. What I want to do is have the same cshtml and browse them the same way I did with Web Pages. If there's MVC in the back I don't even care actually.. @ppumkin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I watched an [ASP.NET Community Standup Meeting Google Hangouts thing on YouTube](http://youtu.be/2aZTmK-ID2E) yesterday where Scott Hanselman, Jon Galloway, and Damian Edwards (Microsoft ASP.NET team members) discussed Web Pages support in ASP.NET 5. They said that it's not in the current build and won't be ready for the 1.0 release of VS 2015. However, it will probably be ready for the 1.1 release, and they mentioned you could probably find several different implementations of it on ASP.NET 5 if you look on GitHub. If I were you, I'd just use MVC until it's ready.

Comment: Oh, so that's why I couldn't find anything on that. Now I need to redo my site in MVC... I'll look some on Github.